# Finding the next term in a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

So this came up in a math competition some of students participated in over the weekend.  Expected highest level of mathematics is calculus 1.

Let $a_n$ be an arithmetic sequence, $b_n$ be a geometric sequence and suppose that $c_n=a_n-b_n$.  The first four terms of $c_n$ are $2, 8, 6, 20$.  Find $c_5$.

My students had two minutes and no calculator to answer this... I've played with this a bit and think that partial sums is probably the direction to go if this is going to be a 2 minute problem but I'm stuck!  I've gotten to a couple spots that I think are along the right direction but perhaps I'm not thinking about this correctly.  Here's what I know:

$c_5=S_5-S_3-c_4$

So if I could find the partial sum at 5 I've got this... The other idea that I have is that the common ratio of the geometric series is $(-b_2)/(b_1)$ (I believe) but I'm still fairly at a loss as how to get our next term.  Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi Ben - I think I've hit upon the "intended" solution (which took me over two minutes). If we write $a_{n+1} - a_n - (b_{n+1} - b_n) = c_{n+1} - c_n$, then we can rewrite as $d - b_n(r - 1) = c_{n+1} - c_n$. From this we can solve for the geometric progression $b_n$ of ratio $r$, and then the arithmetic progression $a_n$ of difference $d$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $d$ denote the common difference of the arithmetic sequence and $r$ denote the common ratio of the geometric sequence.  Then:
\begin{align*}
  c_1 &= a_1 - b_1\\
  c_2 &= a_2 - b_2\\
    &= (a_1 + d) - (b_1r)\\
  c_3 &= a_3 - b_3\\
    &= (a_1 + 2d) - (b_1r^2)\\
  c_4 &= a_4 - b_4\\
    &= (a_1 + 3d) - (b_1r^3)
\end{align*}
And you want to find this value:  $c_5 = a_5-b_5 = (a_1+4d) - (b_1r^4)$.

We have this system:
\begin{align*}
  2 &= a_1 - b_1\\
  8 &= a_1 + d - b_1r\\
  6 &= a_1 + 2d - b_1r^2\\
  20 &= a_1 + 3d - b_1r^3
\end{align*}
It's mildly unpleasant but it's four equations with four variables, and there is indeed a unique solution.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah, we certainly went this way initially and came to this system as well.  Our (the faculty at my school who've been working this) are trying to see if there is an easier way - so that this is solvable in the 2 minute timespan.  Maybe this is it?  Thanks for your response.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, I don't know.  But I do know that math competitions that take place over weekends aren't supposed to be easy.  By that same token there is likely some sort of trick to make this easier/quicker.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think my solution can be calculated within two minutes, but it is pretty straightforward and can be calculated fast too. Let $a_i = x+(i-1)\cdot y$. Since $b_i = a_i-c_i$, we have $$b_2^2 = b_1b_3\implies (x+y-8)^2=(x-2)\cdot(x+2y-6)\implies y^2-12y+52=8x$$
$$b_3^2=b_2b_4 \implies (x+2y-6)^2=(x+y-8)(x+3y-20)\implies y^2+20y-124=-16x$$
Multiplying the first equation by $2$ and adding the second equation, $$3y^2-4y-20=0\implies y=-2,x=10\ \ \text{or} \ \ \ y=\frac{10}{3}, x=\frac{26}{9}$$
The first case is not what we are looking for because it gives $b_2=b_3=0$, so the second case must be true.

Hence, we can get $a_5=x+4y=\frac{146}{9}$. Further, $$b_1=a_1-c_1=\frac{8}{9}, b_2 = a_2-c_2 = -\frac{16}{9}\implies b_5 = \frac{128}{9}$$ Thus, $$c_5=a_5-b_5=\frac{18}{9}=2$$

Comment: Can you clarify why $b^2_3=b_2b_4?$ I'm just not seeing it sorry.

Comment: Because $b_2,b_3,b_4$ is a geometric series, $b_3=b_2\cdot z$ and $b_4=b_2\cdot z^2$ for some $z$, hence $b_3^2=b_2b_4=b_2^2z^2$.